# Convert multidimensional Array to specific String format

Tags: javascript, arrays, stringify

I receive an array that I must convert into a specific string format.

This is the array:

```
formdata: [
    1: {name: "gender", value: "F", focus: 0, type: "radio"}
    2: {name: "firstname", value: "empty", focus: 0, type: "input"}
    3: {name: "lastname", value: "empty", focus: 0, type: "input"}
    4: {name: "birthday", value: "empty", focus: 0, type: "input"}
    5: {name: "street", value: "empty", focus: 0, type: "input"}
    6: {name: "streetNo", value: "empty", focus: 0, type: "input"}
]
```

And this is the specific string format it should be converted to:

```
let formdata = gender.radio|F|0;firstName.text|empty|1;lastName.text|empty|0;street.text|empty|0;houseNumber.text|empty|0;zip.text|empty|0;city.text|empty|0;country.select-one|de|0;birthdate-day.text|empty|0;birthdate-month.text|empty|0;birthdate-year.text|empty|0;email.email|empty|0;code.text|filled_out|0
```

I assume it is best to use JSON.stringify. I have tried several variations along the lines of this:

```
let formdata = JSON.stringify(
formdata: [
    1: {name: "gender", value: "F", focus: 0, type: "radio"}
    2: {name: "firstname", value: "empty", focus: 0, type: "text"}
    3: {name: "lastname", value: "empty", focus: 0, type: "text"}
    4: {name: "birthday", value: "empty", focus: 0, type: "text"}
    5: {name: "street", value: "empty", focus: 0, type: "text"}
    6: {name: "streetNo", value: "empty", focus: 0, type: "text"}
])
.replace(/(\]\]\,)\[/g, "]\n")..replace(/(\[\[|\]\]|\")/g,"");
```

None of them worked.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think just use `map()` on the array. And return Template String. And then `join()` array by `';'`

```js
const formdata = [
    {name: "gender", value: "F", focus: 0, type: "radio"},
    {name: "firstname", value: "empty", focus: 0, type: "input"},
    {name: "lastname", value: "empty", focus: 0, type: "input"},
    {name: "birthday", value: "empty", focus: 0, type: "input"},
    {name: "street", value: "empty", focus: 0, type: "input"},
    {name: "streetNo", value: "empty", focus: 0, type: "input"},
]


let res = formdata.map(({name,value,focus,type}) => `${name}.${type}|${value}|${focus}`).join(';')

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're asking, since your code snippets aren't valid javascript.

But given the array

```
  let formData = [
    {name: "gender", value: "F", focus: 0, type: "radio"},
    {name: "firstname", value: "empty", focus: 0, type: "input"},
    {name: "lastname", value: "empty", focus: 0, type: "input"},
    {name: "birthday", value: "empty", focus: 0, type: "input"},
    {name: "street", value: "empty", focus: 0, type: "input"},
    {name: "streetNo", value: "empty", focus: 0, type: "input"},
  ];
```

If you want a string

```
'gender.radio|F|0;firstName.text|empty|1;lastName.text|empty|0;street.text|empty|0;houseNumber.text|empty|0;zip.text|empty|0;city.text|empty|0;country.select-one|de|0;birthdate-day.text|empty|0;birthdate-month.text|empty|0;birthdate-year.text|empty|0;email.email|empty|0;code.text|filled_out|0'
```

Then this will work:

```
let formDataString = formData.map(({name, value, focus, type}) =>
    `${name}.${type}|${value}|${focus}`);
```

Comment: I can;'t find any difference b/w the mine and your code. and you result will not have `;`

Comment: The difference being the '1', '2', ... numbers and using a colon instead of an equals; these modifications suggested your *array* was a string you wanted to parse into an array.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a helper string for the separators and an object for the replacement values and an array for the wanted keys.

```js
var array = [{ name: "gender", value: "F", focus: 0, type: "radio" }, { name: "firstname", value: "empty", focus: 0, type: "input" }, { name: "lastname", value: "empty", focus: 0, type: "input" }, { name: "birthday", value: "empty", focus: 0, type: "input" }, { name: "street", value: "empty", focus: 0, type: "input" }, { name: "streetNo", value: "empty", focus: 0, type: "input" }],
    keys = ['name', 'type', 'value', 'focus'],
    take = { type: { input: 'text' } },
    separators= '.||',
    string = array
        .map(o => keys
            .map((k, i) => (take[k] && take[k][o[k]] || o[k]) + (separators[i] || ''))
            .join('')
        )
        .join(';');

console.log(string);
```